# modify bootstrap tabs to include sentence, but not display inside of a tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a small issue. I am trying to add a sentence then display the bootstrap tabs right next to the sentence. As you can see, the sentence is inside the tab, but I do not want it. How can i have the sentence appear right in front of the tabs but not be in a tab without compromising the design?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"><!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
 <li class="active" role=""><a aria-controls="home" data-toggle="" href="" role="tab">View different career opportunities</a></li>
 <li class="active" role="presentation"><a aria-controls="home" data-toggle="tab" href="#articles" role="tab">1</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it out and wrap it with a span (with a class `tabtitle`)

Also close your tags `</ul></div>`

#### To change tab height (overwrite bootstrap):

```
.nav>li>a {
    padding: 5px 15px !important;
}
```

```css
.tabtitle {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 10px 0px 25px;
}


.nav>li>a {
    padding: 5px 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <span class="tabtitle">View different career opportunities</span>
    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a aria-controls="home" data-toggle="tab" href="#articles" role="tab">1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to change the height of those tabs? their too tall and not sure which class to modify